# JS Generated span position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There is a HTML code:

```
<div class="caption">
    <h3>t
        <div class="pull-right">
            <span class="label label-primary"> 0 </span>
        </div>
    </h3>

    <span class="label label-info">aaaaaaaaaaa</span>
    <span class="label label-info">aaaaaaaaaaa</span>
    <span class="label label-info">aaaaaaaaaaa</span>
    <span class="label label-info">aaaaaaaaaaa</span>
    <span class="label label-info">aaaaaaaaaaa</span>
</div>
```

Its work good when i reload the browser.
But when i generate this from JS. The spans position was bad!

```
 div_firstcaption = jQuery('<div/>', { //////////
        class: 'caption',
    }).appendTo(div_thumbnail);

    h3 = jQuery('<h3/>', {
        text: 't'
    }).appendTo(div_firstcaption);

    h3_div = jQuery('<div/>', {
        class: 'pull-right'
    }).appendTo(h3);

    h3_div_span = jQuery('<span/>', {
        class: 'label label-primary',
        text: '0'
    }).appendTo(h3_div);

    for(var i = 0; i < 5;i++)
    {
        jQuery('<span/>', {
            class: 'label label-info',
            text: 'aaaaaaaaaaa'+i
        }).appendTo(div_firstcaption);
    }
```

The upper part was good, but the JS generated code is really bad.
What i do wrong? Or just the Browser cant to reposition it?
Whant can i do?
Thanks
[image]

When the Spans do not work good i cant select just one span with double click.
[image]

Comment: Your `label` and `label-info` classes have `width` properties?

Comment: No, just the original bootstrap.css

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: http://pastebin.com/nC73VYQf
The first row is bad.
The second is good, so i just need to enter a space between two span.
How can do this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z5cFw/

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5;i++)
    {
        var g = jQuery('<span/>', {
            class: 'label label-info',
            text: 'aaaaaaaaaaa'
        });
        g.appendTo(div_firstcaption);

        div_firstcaption.append(' ');
    }
```